# Getting connection errors while making a server/client chat program in java

Tags: java, sockets, client, server

I'm nowhere near done with this project yet I'm just trying to make sure things are working and more specifically that the client and server are connecting, and I'm getting connection errors. Here are my two programs. I'm also not entirely sure how to run both of them at once in eclipse so maybe that is the problem. Any help is much appreciated

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {



public  void main(String[] args)throws Exception {

    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3333);;

    while (true)
    {
        Socket clientsocket = server.accept();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(clientsocket.getInputStream());
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());
        String message = "Hello from server";
        p.print(message);
    }

}
```

And heres the client

```
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    Client display = new Client();
    display.setVisible(true);

    try {
    Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(server.getInputStream());
    PrintStream p = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println(sc.next());

    server.close();
    sc.close();
    p.close();


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have some gui stuff above and below the client that I didnt show. When I run these I get the following errors

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Client.main(Client.java:56)
```

and line 56 is the line with -- Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 3333);

Comment: Are you running the server before the client?

Comment: I click run while I have the server tab open. Although, it is opening up the gui thats in my client part so I have a feeling I'm running the client first on accident. How do I make sure I run the server first in eclipse? @John

Comment: Windows shouldn't open when you start the server, why don't you put some output in your server code so that you can figure out what its doing?

Comment: @John okay my server just wasnt running, easy fix and I figured it out! Thanks for the help